# Test mail server tool from toolheap stopped working

Tags: email, updates

This tool has recently stopped working. I have installed Windows updates and Visual Studio 2010 since I last remember it working. Does anybody know why the tool is no longer working or even better how to get it working again?

Edit: The issue is that even though the tool is running, applications will still throw an error implying that there is no SMTP server running.

The tool takes the place of an SMTP server, so emails are never really sent, they are instead stored in a folder. This is exceptionally useful because there is then no chance of ever accidentally emailing anybody. A tool that does the exact same thing would solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a virtual SMTP server that is installed with IIS. I stopped it and the Test Mail Server Tool started running.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I prefer using mxtoolbox.com for doing mail-server testing.  It can verify a great-deal more than any command-line tool I've ever seen.

Also, some additional information about the error you are getting would be useful.